# Block diagonal matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

Given a matrix block diagonal matrix as follows

$${\bf A} =
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
{\bf a}_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\
0 &{\bf  a}_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & {\bf  a}_3& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& {\bf  a}_4
\end{array} \right]$$

where each non zero entry ${\bf a_i}$is $M\times 1$ vector and the zero are also $M\times 1$ vectors. Is it correct to say that the product of this matrix and any other matrix for example ${\bf D}$

$${\bf P = AD} =
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
{\bf a}_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\
0 &{\bf  a}_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & {\bf  a}_3& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& {\bf  a}_4 \\
\end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4 &  \\
d_5 &d_6 &d_7 &d_8\\
d_9 &d_{10} &d_{11} &d_{12}  \\
d_{13}  & d_{14} &d_{15}  & d_{16} &  
\end{array} \right]=\\
\stackrel{=}{?????} \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
{\bf a}_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\
0 &{\bf  a}_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & {\bf  a}_3& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& {\bf  a}_4
\end{array} \right] \times \operatorname{diag} ({\bf D})$$

where $d_i$ are scalars, where $\operatorname{diag} ({\bf D})$ is a matrix with only the diagonal entries of matrix ${\bf D}$?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by an "$M\times 1$ matrix"?  What is $M$?  Take a trivial example where every $a_i$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix equal to $[1]$ (i.e. $A$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix).  What do you know about $AD$ in that case?  Is $AD = A~diag(D)$?

Comment: Sorry I meant $M\times 1$ vector

Comment: Then the product you describe makes little to no sense if $M$ is not equal to one.   Can you give an explicit example for what $A$ looks like if $M$ isn't one?  Something like $\begin{bmatrix}\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a_{1,1}\\a_{1,2}\end{smallmatrix}\right]&0&0&0\\ 0&\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a_{2,1}\\a_{2,2}\end{smallmatrix}\right]&0&0\\0&0&\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a_{3,1}\\a_{3,2}\end{smallmatrix}\right]&0\\0&0&0&\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a_{4,1}\\a_{4,2}\end{smallmatrix}\right]\end{bmatrix}$?  Are those zeroes actually vectors themselves?  My comment from before still holds for A identity

Comment: Yes this exactly the case, why does the prduct make no sense?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking whether $AD=BA\operatorname{diag}(D)$ for some matrix $B$?

Comment: No I am asking if $AD = A \text{diag(D)}$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $M=1$ (so that $A$ is $4\times4$) and the $a_i$'s are all nonzero. Then $A$ is invertible. Do you think the equality $AD=A\operatorname{diag}(D)$ always holds?